# Having this error : Message: unknown error: Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception: Error: LavaMoat - property "JSON"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After updating chrome to 114.0.5735.16, there is error when i try to call elements through xpath, id..

driver get function and refresh seems to work fine

is there something i need to change?

example of codes are these
ex)

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/button")
```

all the errors are same as below

```
Message: unknown error: Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception: Error: LavaMoat - property "JSON" of globalThis is inaccessible under scuttling mode. To learn more visit https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat/pull/360.
  at get (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/runtime-lavamoat.js:11200:17)
  at buildError (<anonymous>:323:13)
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.16)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00496E73+48323]
    (No symbol) [0x00429661]
    (No symbol) [0x00335308]
    (No symbol) [0x003384D6]
    (No symbol) [0x00339991]
    (No symbol) [0x00339A30]
    (No symbol) [0x003607BC]
    (No symbol) [0x00360CDB]
    (No symbol) [0x0038E3D2]
    (No symbol) [0x0037A924]
    (No symbol) [0x0038CAC2]
    (No symbol) [0x0037A6D6]
    (No symbol) [0x0035847C]
    (No symbol) [0x0035957D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006FFD5D+2575277]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0073F86E+2836158]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007396DC+2811180]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005241B0+626688]
    (No symbol) [0x0043314C]
    (No symbol) [0x0042F4B8]
    (No symbol) [0x0042F59B]
    (No symbol) [0x004221B7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77000099+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77207B6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77207B3E+238]
```

all the find element functions, showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting this error. Actually, the problem is due to LavaMoat which is not allowing the websdrive to access password field on the global object.

As of now, the only way to fix the problem is to Download the CRX file and **edit** `scuttleGlobalThis` **in line 93 of the** `runtime-lavamoat.js` file to `false` like below

[image]

After this load it as Unpacked Extension in your Chrome Browser. Your issue would be resolved.

**Remember** that downloading the MetaMask extension from official sources such as the Chrome Web Store ensures the authenticity and security of the extension. Avoid downloading CRX files from unknown or unauthorized sources to minimize the risk of malware or compromised versions.

**Therefore, I would recommend you to manually create the CRX file from steps shown** [here](https://techpp.com/2022/08/22/how-to-download-and-save-chrome-extension-as-crx/).

**BEWARE** - this lowers the security level of MetaMask - use at your own risk.

Find the issue on [Github](https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat/pull/360).

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, and my approach is to lower the Chrome version

Comment: The version I am currently using:  chrome:107.0.5304.122